# Communication in Go via channels

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

Consider such situation. There are one main `goroutine` and ten subsidiary
goroutines. All of them have access to `channel`. Main one sends `1000` numbers to this channel and subsidiary ones will read from it. 
Is there any guarantee that each subsidiary goroutine will read exactly 100  numbers or this amount may vary like some goroutine will read 99 numbers and another 101?

Comment: There is no guarantee, why do you need such guarantee?

Comment: @tkausl to uniformly distribute tasks between goroutines

Comment: Not only is there no such guarantee, there's no reason to even assume that would happen under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no guarantee, because it depends on the runtime of every goroutine and that depends on how well the goroutines are distributed across the CPU.

Comment: Just if it is interesting, I found a blog post [here](https://rakyll.org/scheduler/) about how GoRoutines are scheduled.

Answer (score 1):

With goroutine scheduling via an unbuffered channel, then interesting thing to note is that the channel serves purely as a blocking mechanism - in that the value is never "sent into the channel" and nothing actually "reads from" it.

An unbuffered channel works purely as a synchronization mechanism: for the goroutine sending on a channel, it works more along the lines of "sleep until some goroutine is ready to receive" and for the receiving goroutine it's "sleep until some goroutine is ready to send".

This should make it clear that sends and receives have no kind of fairness or distribution system built in - they're purely first come first served, or possibly even more arbitrary depending on the scheduler's current load.

Comment: In the CSP way of thinking, this distinction is unnecessary and your description doesn't help clarify things. An unbuffered channel is a 'normal' channel through which data events flow. A buffered channel has extended behaviour.

Comment: I'm sure that's a more conceptually correct way of putting things, but the words "data events flow" bring to my mind a pipe or queue - which implies that a data event will be accepted in irrespective of the status of the other end. This isn't how unbuffered channels work in Go, though.